# Как сортировать жанр в кортежах и массивах Python

Tags: python, парсер

Я работаю с API Кинопоиска и не понимаю, как мне сортировать фильмы по жанрам, в выводе у меня это (отформатировано для наглядности):

```
FilmSearchByFiltersResponse(
    total=400,
    totalPages=20,
    items=[
        FoundFilm(
            kinopoisk_id=1252447,
            imdb_id='tt9257638',
            name_ru='Лорды раздевалки',
            name_en=None,
            name_original='Lords of the Lockerroom',
            countries=[
                Country(country='США')
            ],
            genres=[
                Genre(genre='спорт'),
                Genre(genre='для взрослых')
            ],
            rating_kinopoisk=9.4,
            rating_imdb=9.3,
            year=1999,
            type=<FilmType.VIDEO: 'VIDEO'>,
            film_length=None,
            poster_url='https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/images/posters/kp/1252447.jpg',
            poster_url_preview='https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/images/posters/kp_small/1252447.jpg'
        ),
        FoundFilm(
            kinopoisk_id=1043658,
            imdb_id='tt4202274',
            name_ru='Шоу Грязного Фрэнка',
            name_en=None,
            name_original='The Filthy Frank Show',
            countries=[
                Country(country='США'),
                Country(country='Австралия'),
                Country(country='Япония')
            ],
            genres=[
                Genre(genre='фэнтези'),
                Genre(genre='комедия'),
                Genre(genre='музыка'),
                Genre(genre='короткометражка')
            ],
            rating_kinopoisk=9.3,
            rating_imdb=9.4,
            year=2011,
            type=<FilmType.TV_SERIES: 'TV_SERIES'>,
            film_length=None,
            poster_url='https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/images/posters/kp/1043658.jpg',
            poster_url_preview='https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/images/posters/kp_small/1043658.jpg'
        )
    ...
```

Мне нужно, чтобы выводились фильмы с `Genre = 'боевик'`, независимо от других жанров в массиве. Вот мой код:

```
from kinopoisk_unofficial.kinopoisk_api_client import KinopoiskApiClient
from kinopoisk_unofficial.model.filter_country import FilterCountry
from kinopoisk_unofficial.model.filter_order import FilterOrder
from kinopoisk_unofficial.request.films.film_search_by_filters_request import FilmSearchByFiltersRequest
from kinopoisk_unofficial.request.films.filters_request import FiltersRequest


api_client = KinopoiskApiClient("api token")#здесь токен
 
request = FilmSearchByFiltersRequest()
response = api_client.films.send_film_search_by_filters_request(request)

print(response)
```

Comment: Было бы удобней, если бы вы пример содержимого response показали.

Comment: там есть пример response сразу под первым текстом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее так должно сработать

```
genre = response.items[0].genres[0].__class__(genre='боевик') # топорно, но должно сработать
for film in response.items:
    if genre in film.genres:
        print(film)
```

Comment: genre = Genre(genre='боевик')
NameError: name 'Genre' is not defined

Comment: @4aylover я не знаком с этой библиотекой. нужно просто найти где в ней лежит класс `Genre`.

Comment: он не видит Genre

Comment: @4aylover попробуйте запустить теперь

Comment: Работает! единственное response написано неправильно)